# check json property dynamically

Tags: javascript

How to pass propertyName correctly to isValid() function so that I'm able to check if it is not empty? When i directly check for 'searchInside.attendeeList' it works!

```
function isValid(searchInside, propertyName) {
  if(searchInside.propertyName)
    console.log("this doesnt work");
  if(searchInside.attendeeList)
    console.log("this works");
}
var requestBody = {
    "meetingType": "Company",
    "emailSendingReason": "CREATED",
    "attendeeList": [
        {
            "employeeId": "12345",
            "employeeDisplayName": "abc, xyz",
            "callInFlag": false,
            "infoPackRequiredFlag": true,
            "inviteForInfoOnly": true
        },
        {
            "employeeId": "374684678",
            "employeeDisplayName": "xyz, poi",
            "callInFlag": true,
            "infoPackRequiredFlag": true,
            "inviteForInfoOnly": false
        }
    ],
    "thirdPartyAttendee": {}
};
isValid(requestBody, 'attendeeList');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already passing it correctly as a string.
Inside your **isValid()** function you can reference it like:

```
function isValid(searchInside, propertyName) {
  if(searchInside[propertyName]){
    console.log("this works");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `searchInside.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)`. Object **hasOwnProperty()** check for a object key and returns a boolean result.

```
function isValid(searchInside, propertyName) {
  if(searchInside.hasOwnProperty( propertyName)){
    console.log("this works");
  } else console.log("this doesn't work");
}

var requestBody = {
    "meetingType": "Company",
    "emailSendingReason": "CREATED",
    "attendeeList": [
        {
            "employeeId": "12345",
            "employeeDisplayName": "abc, xyz",
            "callInFlag": false,
            "infoPackRequiredFlag": true,
            "inviteForInfoOnly": true
        },
        {
            "employeeId": "374684678",
            "employeeDisplayName": "xyz, poi",
            "callInFlag": true,
            "infoPackRequiredFlag": true,
            "inviteForInfoOnly": false
        }
    ],
    "thirdPartyAttendee": {}
};
isValid(requestBody, 'attendeeList');
```

Comment: yes, i have used hasOwnProperty() for checking existence of property. Now, i want to check if property is not empty. And for this i am using `Object.keys(searchInside.propertyName).length !== 0` which requires `(searchInside.propertyName)` to work.

Comment: Try this. searchInside[propertyName].length !== 0

Answer (score 0):

```
function isValid(searchInside, propertyName) {
  if(typeof searchInside[propertyName] !== 'undefined')
    console.log("this doesnt work");
  if(searchInside.attendeeList)
    console.log("this works");
}
```